# Cannot read property 'requestDevice' of null

Tags: javascript, webgpu

im trying to render web GPU shader object in WebGpu

and it returning this error

***Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestDevice' of null
at cube.html:28***

this is my code to the requestDevice

```
(async () => {
 

    const [adapter, glslang] = await Promise.all([
        navigator.gpu.requestAdapter(),
        import("https://unpkg.com/@webgpu/glslang@0.0.7/web/glslang.js").then(m => m.default())
    ]);

    const device = await adapter.requestDevice();
    
    const canvas = document.getElementById("webgpu-canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

});
```

any idea to fix this error ??

Comment: Afaik, this isn't generally available yet. Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: have you enabled webgpu? It's not shipping yet so you have to turn it on. In Chrome, "about:flags", in firefox "about:config", in Safari you have to turn on the developer menu in preferences and then enable it under experimental features.  see: https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb/wiki/Implementation-Status The spec  for webgpu isn't even done yet so expect things to break.

Comment: yes im using chrome canary Version 89.0.4359.0 and i have enabled webGPU flag

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I fixed it by re-enabling the --enable-unsafe-webgpu flag in about:flags !

Refreshing the page worked before that a couple of times but then stopped... it seems to be fine now!

Answer (score 0):

This happens for one of the following reasons. Check out those in this specific order:

1. WebGPU is disabled when the user has turned off "Use graphics acceleration when available" in `chrome://settings/system`. Check to see if this setting is turned off and turn it back on
2. WebGPU is not supported on this platform yet. You can enable the `chrome://flags/#enable-unsafe-webgpu` flag and restart Chrome. For Linux experimental support, you'll also need to enable the `chrome://flags/#enable-vulkan` flag. Check out [WebGPU support in Headless Chrome](/blog/supercharge-web-ai-testing) to learn more.
3. The GPU hardware has been specifically blocklisted. If you see "WebGPU has been disabled via blocklist or the command line" in `chrome://gpu`, you can disable the WebGPU adapters blocklist by enabling the `chrome://flags/#enable-unsafe-webgpu` flag and restarting Chrome.
4. There is no matching GPU adapter for the options passed in `requestAdapter()`. [Try calling `requestAdapter()` with different options](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#dictdef-gpurequestadapteroptions).
5. WebGPU requires a GPU (either hardware or software-emulated). You can check if Chrome detects a GPU by visiting `chrome://gpu`.

See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/webgpu/troubleshooting-tips for more tips